# Retrofit не корректное поведение

Tags: android

В приложений вызываю апи(Rx/Retrofit) , 
когда сервак возвращает 200  = все ок,
Но если возвращает 520 внутренню ошибку , и другую модель ответа,
Retrofit излучает success , Разве при несоответствий полей он должен в error кидать?

```
fun transferOwnToOwn(@Body params: OwnToOwnUseCase.Params): Single<BaseResponse<TransferAmountResponse>>
```

в репо:

```
fun <T> request(call: Single<BaseResponse<T>>): Single<T> {
    return call.flatMap {
        if (it.code == 200) {
            Single.just(it.data)
        } else {
            //Вот тут выдает ошибку так , так прилетает BaseResponse<T> с null значениями
            val  errorResponse = it.data as ErrorResponse
            Single.error<T>(BusinessLogicException(it.toString()))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вроде нет. Ошибка в retrofit - это когда до сервера запрос не дошел, а неверные ответы вы сами должны обрабатывать

Comment: Странно , до этого казалось если поля в моделки не совпадают, он должен выбрасывать исключение)

Comment: Исключение будет если имя поля совпадает, а тип нет. А так же если ожидается объект, а пришёл массив и наоборот. В остальных случаях поля из ответа проигнорируются, а в POJO останутся с дефолтными значениями (нулями, если не задано иное)

Comment: ok, спасибо за развернутый ответ!